# Twig automatically removes apostrophe and quotation marks

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've created my own `TransTokenParser` for the sake of learning (parsing `{% trans %}` and `{% trans with %}`) -> and the parser itself works good except for the latter variant: `trans with`.

The parser reads out the variables assigned, yet automatically escapes `"` and `'` so thus they don't display (the variables come out without `'` or `"` directly from the parser).

For example, we have this block in a twig:

```
{% trans with {'{test}': coolFunctionWhichReturnsString('testParameter')} %}
UNIQUE_TRANS_ID
{% endtrans %}
```

This block gets parsed fine with the trans and whatnot, but turns the part after 'with' to this:  `{{test}: coolFunctionWhichReturnsString(testParameter)}`

I've tried setting a parameter in Twig_Environment

```
new Twig_Environment(..., ['autoescape' => false])
```

I've tried setting a global in config.yml under twig:

```
autoescape: false
```

None of the both solutions reflect changes on the behaviour of twig -> php. (It sets the autoescape to false, as seen in the var_dump upon initializing the twig environment here:

```
array (size=13)
  'debug' => boolean true
  'charset' => string 'UTF-8' (length=5)
  'base_template_class' => string 'Twig_Template' (length=13)
  'strict_variables' => boolean true
  'autoescape' => boolean false
```

This is my code:

```
/**
 * @return array
 * @throws \Twig_Error_Syntax
 */
private function parseVariant(): array
{
    $stream = $this->parser->getStream();
    $trans = null;
    $json = null;
    //SIMPLE VARIANT trans
    $stream->nextIf(\Twig_Token::PUNCTUATION_TYPE, '');
    if (null !== $stream->nextIf(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE)) { //%} TRANS_LITERAL
        $stream->nextIf(\Twig_Token::PUNCTUATION_TYPE, '');
        $trans = $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::TEXT_TYPE)->getValue();
    } elseif (null !== $stream->nextIf(\Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE, 'with')) { // {% trans with {} %} TRANS_LITERAL
        $stream->next();
        $json = implode($this->getInlineParams());
        $stream->nextIf(\Twig_Token::PUNCTUATION_TYPE);
        $stream->nextIf(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);
        $stream->nextIf(\Twig_Token::PUNCTUATION_TYPE);
        $trans = $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::TEXT_TYPE)->getValue();
        //die();
    }
    // {% endtrans %}
    $stream->nextIf(\Twig_Token::PUNCTUATION_TYPE);
    $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_START_TYPE);
    $stream->nextIf(\Twig_Token::PUNCTUATION_TYPE);
    $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE);
    $stream->nextIf(\Twig_Token::PUNCTUATION_TYPE);
    $endLine = $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE)->getLine();

    return [$json, $trans, $endLine];
}
```

The issue is with $json, which refers to in this case:

```
$json = implode($this->getInlineParams());
```

get inline params:

```
protected function getInlineParams(): array
{
    $stream = $this->parser->getStream();
    $params = [];
    while (!$stream->test(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE)) {
        $params[] = $this->parser->getStream()->next()->getValue();
    }
    $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);

    return $params;
}
```

Edit: Using an ExpressionParser throws errors, as the key/values have no "" or ''..

Another edit: I've already tried modifying the "escaper" extension on both runtime and post-initialization in twig including all strategies - nothing helped

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have much time to answer on this, could be I give this a closer look on monday. Anyway at this point I'd suggest you take a look at `IncludeToken`, see [here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/2.x/src/TokenParser/IncludeTokenParser.php#L47) - I'm sure you can get some inspiration there

Comment: Twig's syntax for binding variable keys is as follows `{% set object = { (key1): "a string", (key2): some_function(3) } %}` where `key1` and `key2` are variables holding strings. It's probably easier for you to stick with this syntax.

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich That is not the issue OP is facing. The problem is happening when `twig` is compiling the template into `PHP` to render it

Comment: First, thanks to everyone participating in the comments section trying to find a solution. @DarkBee : Looking forward to a reply on monday! I'll look into the link you referenced.

@ NicolaiFröhlich please assume that I am not able to edit the twig at all -> thus changing twig files to any format is not applicable. :)

Comment: I wonder why you don't take a look at the twig-bridge-bundle, which *should* contain the original trans Node stuff.

Comment: Are you referring to the TransTokenParser? I figured out such class exists post-creation of my own version. That put aside, I've learned a bunch whilst writing/conceptioning this, especially since I'm pretty new to PHP/the Symfony framework. Maybe that'll stop you from wondering. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a two-fold problem: the first is a probably way to simple logic in the `getInlineParams` function, which might not be problematic for these simple cases, but it might be horrendous for more sophisticated cases.

the second problem is the complete ignorance of types.

```
{'{test}': coolFunctionWhichReturnsString('testParameter')}
```

gets parsed to (read as "string value" - "token type"):

- `{` - block start
- `{test}` - a string
- `:` - a punctuation
- `coolFunctionWhichReturnsString` - a name
- `(` - (not sure which type)
- `testParameter` - a string
- `)` - (again)
- `}` - block end

the first problem will unfold, when you nest multiple {}. 
the second problem is due to one simple fact:

the **type** matters.

a lexer has a very important task, it removes all the different variants users may choose to express strings, comments, it removes irrelevant whitespace (because it's just clutter), and so on. now, if you treat every `Token` (which have a value and a type) as if it's just some weird object that contains the string you want, you got a problem - obviously.

so, if you want to recreate something similar to the original input, you have to look at the types and add quotes when the type is a string. (text is probably all stuff outside of blocks)

(**this would be the quick "solution" to your stated problem**)

However, ignoring the semantics of tokens will cause problems in the long run... because you also have to somehow handle the "coolFunctionWhichReturnsString", i.e., you have to turn it into some function call. Theoretically, you should really build an AST and compile it into the appropriate form at some point...

the twig parser uses a method [`subparse`](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/38341bbefdaf496e0752c90b053c54ed23d57f98/src/Parser.php#L129) to parse stuff until some "end" comes up. (building up an AST, because structure matters too at some point)

**update**: as it turns out, there is a page for writing node parsers in the twig docs, and it possibly simplifies this a lot, if you follow https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#registering-a-new-tag (information starts slightly above "Registering a new tag" and very much simplifies the parsing and usage of the value)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your input - I completely understand your point and will be looking forward to consider the type of every parsed token via getInlineParams() on Monday! What a pity that I completely ignored Token types. Perhaps, I've already looked into subparse, yet it always set the parser in a "bad state" -> thus I've vastly seeked for an alternative in which the method 'getInlineParams()' displayed handy. I assume because I'm reading it out in a wrong order -> I'll update this on monday!

Comment: @sh0ck well good luck. please don't let this question mutate into something completely different that at some point more resembles a "how to write a parser for a twig block" (that would violate the spirit of questions on SO)

Comment: @sh0ck stumbled over the twig documentation about registering a new tag (see update), which definitely gives a blueprint on how this is supposed to be done.

Comment: Wow! I wish I'd have seen this earlier. it doesn't simplify anything at all except replacing the getInlineParams with an expressionParser - which I've already mentioned is something I already tried using! (I should've posted my whole class) :=) I'll give it a try again, going to keep you updated on monday - have a nice weekend until then. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out that they get parsed into different types - I've totally forgot about it. Appreciate the help!